# How to determine tableau server version?

Tags: tableau-api

I've searched for this for a whole day.
Can someone please tell me how I can view the Tableau server version???

Folder/file references only goes up to the first decimal ie 8.1
That's not accurate enough. Couldn't find it in the admin portal either.

I need to find the exact version ie 8.1.6

Thanks

Gemmo

Comment: what's the output of `tabcmd version` ?

Comment: Tableau Server Command Line Utility -- Version 8100.14.0408.1805

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In tableau 8 and below, you can have the exact version number by accessing Tableau Server through your web browser.
If you navigate in the menus, it will be at the bottom of the pages, like this:

[image: Tableau Server Version Screenshot]

Hope this helps.

Comment: in Tableau 9 I see the version number under "About <ServerName>" under the menu that's a little 'i' in the top right.  There is nothing at the bottom of the pages that I can see.

Comment: Thanks fcrick for letting us know. I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the tableau server logs, look in the tabadmin.log file for the build number.

Should the installation be in the default location, tabadmin.log is located in:
C:\ProgramData\Tableau\Tableau Server\logs

It will be in the latest entry, similar to:
2014-07-14 14:28:59.929 +0100_DEBUG_10.62.1.44:HOSTNAME :_pid=11504_0x3297d38__user=**request=** ====>>  8.2 (build: 8200.14.0611.2328): Starting at 2014-07-14 14:28:59.905 +0100 <<====

Answer (score 1):

Hey there are two ways you could determine the exact version and build of tableau

1. from the Tableau portal, on the right corner of the screen you will see (i) of Information icon next to logged in user name, if you click on the icon, click on About tableau Server you get the complete information like version, build, and so example ( Tableau Server Version: 10.1.0 (10100.16.0915.1805) 64-bit )
2. tabcmd version

   ```
   tabcmd version
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   Tableau Server Command Line Utility -- 10100.16.0915.1805
   ```